# MathJax numbering equations wrongly

Tags: latex, mathjax, tex

MathJax is numbering equation's lines that are given with \cr, \newline or \\ separately where it should be a single number for whole equation.

The equation;

```
\begin{align}
    \ket{\lo}\ket{\lo} & \underset{U_f}{\to} \ket{\lo} \ket{\lo \oplus f(\lo)} \cr 
    \ket{\li}\ket{\lo} & \underset{U_f}{\to} \ket{\li} \ket{\lo \oplus f(\li)} \cr
    \ket{\lo}\ket{\li} & \underset{U_f}{\to} \ket{\lo} \ket{\li \oplus f(\lo)} \cr 
    \ket{\li}\ket{\li} & \underset{U_f}{\to} \ket{\li} \ket{\li \oplus f(\li)} \, .
\end{align}
```

Renders as:

[image: screenshot]

the original pdf:

[image: screenshot]

is there a way to prevent MathJax to number equation's aligned lines?

and this is how MathJax numbering configured

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }
});
```

thanks

Comment: That's the way `align` works. You can place `\nonumber` before ``\\`` in each line you don't want to have a number. As an aside, where would you go to see the rendered output with your code snippet? I can't seem to replicate the numbered equations on [math.se].

Comment: Please share a live sample via codepen, jsbin etc. I suspect you have configured MathJax's auto-numbering incorrectly. See the docs at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering

Comment: It looks like `\cr` implies `\nonumber`, which I didn't know, and so didn't implement in MathJax.  That is a bug.  The numbering is correct if `\\` were used, but `\cr` seems to suppress the number.  I will also need to check `\newline` and what it does.

Comment: Need to be careful as I think there are some conditions for numbering line breaks, e.g if `\cr` is in a matrix like `\begin{pmatrix}  1\cr 0 \end{pmatrix}`, this doesnt mean it would imply `\nonumber`

Comment: See also David Carlisle's comment [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/871).  It appears that `\cr` is not supported in LaTeX environments, so the TeX code technically is invalid (though the error is not reported).